# Overriding a view of spring-boot-admin-server-ui without changing functionality

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am using SBA application to monitor my applications in kubernetes.

I am using `spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-host-type=IP` as due to missing dns entries my SBA was not able to resolve the hostnames of client pods.

Now the issue is that the instance identifier is coming as internal pod IP and this instance identifier is a clickable link in `spring-boot-admin-3.1.1\spring-boot-admin-server-ui\src\main\frontend\views\applications\instances-list.vue`

Is there any way to make this non-clickable or override this value without changing functionality as everything is working fine, just clicking this internal IP is giving unreachable url.

Is there any way to override only `instances-list.vue` without changing functionality. By overriding i am thinking of removing this href

```
<template>
  <li
    v-for="instance in instances"
    :key="instance.id"
    :data-testid="instance.id"
    class="flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 p-2"
    @click.stop="showDetails(instance)"
  >
    <div class="pr-3 md:w-16 text-center">
      <sba-status
        :date="instance.statusTimestamp"
        :status="instance.statusInfo.status"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/3 truncate">
      <a
        :href="
          instance.registration.serviceUrl || instance.registration.healthUrl
        "
        @click.stop
        v-text="
          instance.registration.serviceUrl || instance.registration.healthUrl
        "
      /><br />
      <span class="text-sm italic" v-text="instance.id" />
    </div>
```

I have tried using spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-host-type= host-name & canonical-host-name also but due to missing host entries i had to use ip method only.